# Create an object using one of the constructor in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, class, object, constructor

I'm new to the Android app development and OOP. I created a Kotlin class file in my java folder as I'm using Kotlin to develop my app.

The Kotlin class file contains the code below `class Users (FirstName : String , LastName : String?, UserName : String, PassWord : String, Phone : Int, Age : Int , Weight : Int, Height : Int){}`

May I know is the class I created in the Kotlin class file is a Public class or not? Besides, can I used one of the constructor of the object to create an object of that class?

Comment: That bit in parentheses *is* the constructor, you can actually write `class Users constructor(...)` if you want. You can call it with `Users()` but with all the parameters you've listed inside the parentheses, and they have to be in order (there are ways around that but that's for later). This is really the basics, so if you're unfamiliar with this stuff you should definitely check out some learning resources! There's some on the Kotlin site: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/learning-materials-overview.html - the koans are cool because it's about fixing problems, and you can do them in the browser

Comment: owhhh, thanks for your suggestion. I will try it. However, I tried to watch the videos on youtube discussing about the constructor. In my understanding constructor is an initialization of the properties and the assignment of the values to corresponding properties. Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: A constructor just creates an instance of the class. The parameters you pass can be used by the constructor during initialisation - and if you have multiple constructors, the one that gets called is the one that matches the parameters you passed (same types in the same order). A constructor can do whatever it wants, it doesn't *have* to store the values of those parameters as properties - it might just decide on some values based on what's passed in. In Kotlin, you can add `val` or `var` before a parameter to *make it* a property though, as a shorthand

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is so helpful to me and I am clear now!

Answer (score 0):

The classes in kotlin by default are public.

in kotlin you can have one primary constructor or some secondary constructors.

Primary constructor sample:

```
class Test(
    private val a: Int,
    private val b: Int) {}
```

Secondary constructors sample:

```
class Test {

// First secondary constructor
constructor(a: Int)

// Second secondary constructor
constructor(a: Int, b: Int) }
```

Comment: Owhhh, thanks for your answer. However, is there any ways for me to create an object with a class by having a constructor inputted as its name?

Comment: @RTTZ159
You can create instance of Test class like below:
1- val object1 = Test(a = 1)
************************************
2- val object2 = Test(a = 1, b = 2)

Comment: So there is no such thing as 1- val phone = 012345678 ***2- val name = Alan*** 3- val name = User( phone, name )  ? Assuming I have a class of User which have the constructor of phone and name.